# Does $M$ such that 1) $M^TM=I$ and 2) $M^*(M^*)^T=I$, implies $M^*M=I$?

Tags: matrices

Does $M$, a $n\times n$ matrix with complex entries, such that 1) $M^TM=I$ and 2) $M^*(M^*)^T=I$, implies $M^*M=I$?

Comment: I guess $M^*$ means the conjugate transpose of $M$, right? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose Also, I think you would like to say $M^* (M^*)^T=I$, is that correct?

Comment: Notice however that $M^*(M^*)^T=I$ (with $M^*$ the conjugate transponse) is just a re-statement of $M^TM=I$.

Comment: @Tony correct - edited.

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M^TM=I$ if and only if $M^*(M^T)^*=I^*=I$. Since $(M^T)^*=(M^*)^T=\overline M$, we have $(1)\Leftrightarrow(2)$. And obviously $(1)$ does not imply unitary.

Answer (score 3):

No. Consider $M=\pmatrix{\sqrt{2}&-i\\ i&\sqrt{2}}$ for instance.